# jQuery/NodeJS: Getting URL of a button without unique class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, cheerio

So I'm trying to get a certain link of a button on a website I parse via NodeJS:

Usually, it would be fairly easy when using cheerio:

```
$('.panel-default').find('.btn-default').attr('href');
```

The problem is: There are 3 other buttons with the same classname, on overall 60 items:

```
<a href="https://someurl.com" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-fw fa-steam-square poptip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="View Details"></span></a>

<a href="/somedir" class="btn btn-xs btn-default"><span class="fa fa-road fa-fw poptip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="See more like this"></span></a>

<a href="/otherdir" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-link fa-fw poptip" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="View shareable link"></span></a>
```

So looping through the 4 results with .each, picking the right one, and repeat that on all 60 other items don't seem like an elegant choice for me.

Is there any other way to grab the wanted info, for example by calling the unique data-original-title "Inspect in game" via cheerio (is that even possible?) for example? Or how else could this be solved in an elegant and smooth way?

Comment: If you know what it is you're exactly looking for, why not query for that specifically?

Comment: I would love to do that! The only unique part is the "data-original-title", though. How do I "select" that? I haven't found any reference on that, sadly.

My only other idea was to do a string search and cut the interesting part via regex - which doesn't seem really elegant as well.

Answer (score 0):

If `$('.panel-default').find('.btn-default')` return more than one value, you can pass index that you want to get just her href attribute.

If you want the second element href by example :

`$('.panel-default').find('.btn-default')[1].attr('href');`

Comment: I only returns one, the first, result (which is the the wrong one). To get all 4 I would have to use the .each function first, I guess, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Try to use vanilla and select with index. ```document.querySelectorAll('.panel-default .btn-default')[1].href; ```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data` selector.

```
$('.panel-default').find(".btn-default[data-original-title='Microsoft']").attr('href');
```

Comment: @OP I had to readjust this answer, as I misunderstood the `data` method. Try the edited answer, though I'm not sure if Cheerio supports data selectors at this point.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this looked promising, however when I tried

$('.panel-default').find(".btn-default[data-original-title='See more like this']").attr('href');

The result was undefined :(

Comment: "data selector"?  This is an attribute selector.  The attribute just happens to be a data attribute.

Comment: @Taplar you're right. It was simply a fumble of words.